# maven-surefire-plugin strange behaviour

Tags: maven, junit, maven-surefire-plugin

I've got a problem with maven-surefire-plugin reports. Maven version is 3.3.9, maven-surefire-plugin 2.18.1, version of JUnit is 4.12.

Tests run in Jenkins, there should be info after each test, but sometimes something goes wrong and there is no info in Console and there are no surefire reports.

Should be something like that

```
11:07:42 Tests run: 8, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 194.569 sec - in com.example.content.SomeTest
11:07:42 
11:07:42 Results :
11:07:42 
11:07:42 Tests run: 8, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0
11:07:42 
11:07:42 [INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------------
11:07:42 [INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
11:07:42 [INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------------
11:07:42 [INFO] Total time: 03:17 min
11:07:42 [INFO] Finished at: 2017-11-15T11:07:39
11:07:42 [INFO] Final Memory: 15M/377M
11:07:42 [INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------------
```

But as I said sometimes there are no these lines. Previous and next test classes work fine and have all info and reports as it supposed to be

Is this problem really caused by surefire-plugin or maybe it's something different?

Comment: First how could someone know who is causing the issue (assuming there is one) if we have not a log file etc. and a particular reproducible test case for the issue..? Apart from that I don't see the relationship to the linked issue ? Furthermore It's not really clear what exactly is your problem? error output / logfile output ?

Comment: Tests are always different and it's doesn't depend on which test run at all. And it's just impossible to put all of them here.

The main problem is that plugin does not create report files for some random test

com.example.content.SomeTest.txt
TEST-com.example.content.SomeTest.xml

And at the same time output in console is incorrect, 'cause it doesn't contain lines with test run results.

Main idea - it might be the bug in maven-surefire-plugin version 2.18.1

Comment: There might be bugs anywhere ...the problem is to nail it down we need at log files which shows there is something wrong and furthermore the appropriate code to reproduce it otherwise it's more or less impossible to find something like this...if it exists...